# How to unparse and measure the height of a binary tree

Tags: struct, scheme, binary-tree, racket

So for my HW, using these structs:

```
(define-struct Plus (tl tr))
(define-struct Neg (t))
(define-struct Times (tl tr))
```

I have to solve for the following:

height : num-tree -> num which counts the number of nodes in the longest branch of the tree.

and

unparse : num-tree -> string to construct the Racket expression matching the given tree.

An example for each are the following:

```
(height (make-Plus (make-Neg (make-Times 3 4)) (make-Neg 6)))
 => 4
```

and

```
(unparse (make-Plus (make-Neg (make-Times 3 4)) (make-Neg 6)))
=> "(+ (- (* 3 4)) (- 6))"
```

My questions for the height problem is how can I check which is the longest side of a given tree? When I have a struct with two arguments (lets say Times), how can I check, which one  has the longer branch? A previous problem had us solve the size of the tree but the thing is, it is really easy to solve for the size of a tree since you just do +1 to all of the conditions until you reach the base case. The height is different because you do not want to count both the nodes of the left and the right of the tree, but only count the one that has the biggest height.

For unparse, we also had to do a problem that has us evaluate the number tree. However, I do not know how to tackle this since you cannot really use the evaluate function that I made in order to solve this problem.

Any suggestions to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For procedure `height`, you simply need to use `max` if the structure has 2 fields:

```
(define (height tree)
  (cond
    ((Plus? tree)  (add1 (max (height (Plus-tl tree))  (height (Plus-tr tree)))))
    ((Times? tree) (add1 (max (height (Times-tl tree)) (height (Times-tr tree)))))
    ((Neg? tree)   (add1 (height (Neg-t tree))))
    (else          1)))
```

For `unparse` it's just a matter of concatenating strings, no evaluation needed:

```
(define (unparse tree)
  (cond
    ((Plus? tree)   (format "(+ ~a ~a)" (unparse (Plus-tl tree))  (unparse (Plus-tr tree))))
    ((Times? tree)  (format "(* ~a ~a)" (unparse (Times-tl tree)) (unparse (Times-tr tree))))
    ((Neg? tree)    (format "(- ~a)"    (unparse (Neg-t tree))))
    (else           (format "~a" tree))))
```

Testing:

```
(define x (make-Plus (make-Neg (make-Times 3 4)) (make-Neg 6)))
(height x)
=> 4
(unparse x)
=> "(+ (- (* 3 4)) (- 6))"
```